# Request a JWT from azure B2C application in ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have two APIs.

1. Admin API (.NET Core API)
2. Healthcare API (Azure function API)

I need to call an endpoint in Healthcare API, and it should be called from admin API. I know the best way is to use gRPC but no time for that now.

Healthcare API is authorized with an azure b2c application. And the admin API is authorized with another azure b2c application. So from Admin API, I can't call the Healthcare API because of this authorization. (Can't use allow anonymous because it's an azure function API)

One solution that came to my mind is to get a jwt token in Admin API, from the b2c application that used to authorize healthcare API. But o idea of how to do this.

Is the above solution is good? And is it doable? Are there any ways of doing this without moving into gRPC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this guide will be helpful for you to finish the process: getting JWT token and access healthcare API that protected by B2C : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: @StanleyGong the problem is these two APIs are authorized with two different B2C applications.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: @StanleyGong Not yet sir. I'm trying this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications 

And there also have an issue with Azure B2C. it does not support to client credential grant type.  Trying some workarounds

Answer (score 0):

If these 2 B2C apps belong to the same B2C tenant, and you just want to make admin API to call Healthcare API, maybe you can just use OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow.

Although the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow is not currently directly supported by the Azure AD B2C authentication service, you can set up client credential flow using Azure AD and the Microsoft identity platform /token endpoint for an application in your Azure AD B2C tenant. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with Azure AD enterprise tenants.

just as below:
[image]

Comment: B2C is not supporting for client credential flow, right?

Comment: No, but actually B2C inherits part of Azure AD functionality so that you can use client credential flow in B2C just like you use it in common Azure AD.

Comment: I tried this method. And I got a token when I use 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' as the scope. But with that token, I can't call the API. Still got 401. When I use 'https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/lab-api/read', getting an error saying 'AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid'

Comment: And then I used https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/lab-api/.default. That also gives 401